# React is retrieving firebase data thrice

Tags: reactjs, firebase

**BACKGROUND:**

I am trying to retrieve data and plot a pie-chart using react google charts.

**PROBLEM**

Data is being retrieved thrice (which should not happen)

**CODE**

I have console logged the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3vmo6xw4n1?fontsize=14

Any suggestions,hint would be helpful,
thanks in advance

Comment: It's console logging multiple times because you have a for loop encased inside a foreach loop. It is not because data is fetched multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebaseLooper is pushing three objects to data. Removing that for each loop and only push once should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The *console.log* happened multiple times because you had used a *foreach* inside a for loop. Change the code as below and it would work fine.

Note that I have used `data` instead of snapshot for the *foreach*. You can also use *snapshot*.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var subpath = "Maternal/ChildRegistration";
    ///AVgYUYIzOnYnh7D4a5ImKjM63mp2/${subpath}
    var countMale = 0;
    var countFemale = 0;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`users`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        var count = 0;
        const data = firebaseLooper(snapshot);
        var i;
        var currentsupervisorid = "7Fd8iLXHNlR7qHhdx9DouciKfbC2";
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(child => {
          if (child.anganwadidetails.supervisorid === currentsupervisorid) {
            console.log(child);
          }
        });
        this.setState({
          value1: countMale,
          value2: countFemale
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("error returned - ", e);
      });
  }
```